# an unhandled exception Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException

Tags: c#

I have an issue about Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException.

If i started manually, it works fine.

but when i try to start by windows task scheduler,

it said

'ResolutionFailedException was unhandled'

Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "MainPresenter", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: Calling constructor XX.Main().
Exception is: FormatException - Input string was not in a correct format.

This is my Code :

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
using (IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer())
{
  container.RegisterType<IMainView, Main>();
  MainPresenter presenter = container.Resolve<MainPresenter>();
  Application.Run((Form)presenter.View);
}
```

Main Code :

```
public partial class Main : Form, IMainView
{
    public Main()
    {
    }
}
```

IMainView Code :

```
public interface IMainView
{
}
```

MainPresenter Code :

```
public class MainPresenter
{
    public MainPresenter( IMainView view )
    {
        this.view = view;
    }
    public IMainView View
    {
        get { return view; }
    }
    private readonly IMainView view;
}
```

Program Code :

```
static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        /// 

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {

            bool bNew;
            Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "XX", out bNew);

            if (bNew)
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                using (IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer())
                {
                    container.RegisterType<IMainView, Main>();
                    MainPresenter presenter = container.Resolve<MainPresenter>();
                    Application.Run((Form)presenter.View);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the constructor code? Apparently it throws an exception but with no code it is not possible no say why it does so.

Comment: I just edited. Is it OK?

Comment: Are you sure `Main`'s constructor is empty? I bet it calls `InitializeComponents` and this is why it throws the exception - for some reason `InitializeComponents` fail.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't write that. InitializeComponent() is in Main(). But exception throw at 
-- MainPresenter presenter = container.Resolve<MainPresenter>(); --
in Program.cs

Comment: Your right. InitializeComponent() throws exception. How can I fix it?

Comment: That's another question and it is unrelated to Unity. For some reason your `InitializeComponent` method fails when run from within the scheduler. Debug it and/or create another SO question.

Comment: I think i found the problem. When Main form load, i call the ini file
and at that time the exception comes up. And i still don't know why it can't call ini file when it started by task scheduler. I'm sorry bother you.

Comment: I figure it out. It was path problem. I used dynamic path for ini file path. So I change to static path and it works. Thank you!!